# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.determineTimeout

Tags: spring, hibernate

**org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException**: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.determineTimeout(Lorg/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition;)
      at...
Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.determineTimeout**(Lorg/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition;)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:289)
    ... 55 more

**i try to find this method at package org.springframework.jdbc.datasource and found that method determineTimeout in "int timeout = determineTimeout(definition);" is not exists.**

```
maven dependency
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
        <spring.version>5.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>5.4.2</junit.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>
        <jdbc-mysql.version>8.0.16</jdbc-mysql.version>
        <inject.version>1</inject.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <commons.version>2.6.0</commons.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Can you verify if there are no classpath issues. Checking javadoc for the `https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html` , looks like determineTimeout is inherited from `org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager`

Comment: Can you post full POM file?

Comment: i found that spring-dao and spring-tx both have the org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager,  and  use the one of spring-dao, which has no determineTimeout()!! thank you.